# How to set up Docker for Symfony project with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker

How to set up a new Symfony project with MySQL database using Docker?

I've been trying to set up a new project using Docker for over a week now. I've read trough Docker documentation, found a few tutorials, but nothing really worked for me. And I'm just not able to crack how Docker set up works. Last time I tried I just got a RuntimeException and an ErrorException errors

Project Structure:

```
-myProject
  -bin
    -...
  -config
    -...
  -docker
    -build
      -php
        -Dockerfile
  -php
  -public
    -index.php
  -src
    -...
  -var
    -...
  -vendor
    -...
  -docker-compose.yaml
  -...
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/build/php/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8100:80"

  # Configure the database
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-root}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

I expected to have "Welcome to Symfony" page but I got an error page.
Errors:

```
ErrorException
Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainerDeprecations.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

AND

```
RuntimeException
Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/www/html/var/cache/dev)
```

What I need is some help to set up my Symfony 4 project with MySQL using Docker

Comment: Hi, I don't work with php so I can't assist that much but one thing you might one to correct and maybe that makes it work as well: When you set "context: ." in docker-compose.yml and then run "COPY . /var/www/html/" in Dockerfile, then what you copy is everything in your current folder. Judging from your folder structure this might not be what you want

Comment: Hi, To be honest I'm not sure anymore how  I could fix it. I have added my projects structure to the post

Comment: Can't give you a detailed answer right now, but I suggest you take a look at the Sylius setup. They're really serious about code quality. https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard

Comment: How do you run it locally without docker? There are really a lot of pages that explain "docker sympfony 4", I am sure you  can find one that works for you

Comment: @Mihai in his defence, there are a lot of pages that have outdated, incomplete or just plain wrong advice.

Comment: @Mihai To tell you the truth this is a completely new project. Firstly I have created a Symfony project and then decided to use Docker. Before that I just used PHP's built in server while I was learning Symfony

Comment: OMG chmod worked! Wheres the guy that told me to chmod the VAR file? He solved my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so to make it work I just needed to give permision to var folder using chmod in Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.2-apache

COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/
```

Found this answer in the comments, but the person that left it removed the comment

Comment: You can also do this: `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html`. Be sure to run commands with that user next, though.

Answer (score 0):

You actualy have no need to chmod your project root folder to something unnecessary open, like 0777.

In php:* containers php workers run from www-data user. So all you need to do is chown your current project root dir to www-data and verify that www-data user can actualy create folders in it (ls -lah will help you).

Here is my php stage from symfony 4.3 projects:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm as runtime

# install php ext/libraries and do other stuff.

WORKDIR /var/www/app
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=composer /app/vendor vendor
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data bin bin
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data config config
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data public public
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data src src
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data .env .env
```